# Dynamically filter features if they are within another layer using QGIS filter query expression

Tags: qgis

I have a point layer file with bus stops and am trying dynamically filter to only display within a polygon (45 minute Public transport catchment).

Ideally, the filter query will calculate which points are within the polygon by using feature query expression.

Im new to using expressions and trying something like this

```
within($geometry ,get_feature("45 minute polygon",,)
```

I am avoiding Vector-> geoprocessing tools because the the polygon will change and I am trying to do this in an automated way.

Comment: Do you use the provider feature filter? If so, what format is your datasource? If not, where do you apply this filter?